# Re-direct loop when checking if value is null C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, redirecttoaction

I am getting results based on an ID which is passed into the controller via the URL, for example Site/View/12 - this will bring back all results that match 12.

However, if there are no results, I want to re-direct back to the Index page which also has the search field.

```
public new ActionResult View(string ID = "")
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
    var bikes = (xml).ToList();

    if (!bikes.Any())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(bikes);
    }
}
```

However, whilst trying to view any page (/Add, /Index etc) I get a **"This webpage has a redirect loop"** error.

I'm not quite sure what's going on, because as far as I can tell viewing these pages shouldn't even trigger anything inside `ActionResult View()`. Also, the `RedirectToAction` is going to `Index` - so I cannot figure out where the loop is.

If I remove the line `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` the application functions normally.

Any advice would be very welcome, thank you.

(edit) Here's the Index controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And here's the RouteConfig.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: post the code for the index page I bet there is something going on there

Comment: Also post your RouteConfig (or wherever you configure your routes).

Comment: Thank you both, I've just updated my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controller has a View method to return the view, but your Action method is also named View, and that's where it gets stuck.  Change your action to be:

```
[ActionName("View")]
public new ActionResult ViewItem(string ID = "")
```

And everything should work OK.

Answer (score 3):

Your action is named `View`.  When you do

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

it's defaulting to your method (the optional parameter makes it valid):

```
public new ActionResult View(string ID = "")
```

If you mouseover `return View()` intellisense will tell you which `View()` its calling.  Rename your `View` action and you'll see that the intellisense changes which `View()` is referenced, and it should work fine.  Using an attribute to keep your action as `View` seems like its just going to cause another confusing headache later.

Comment: Thank you! I've actually gone with Brian's solution as it doesn't require me to re-write any code, but in future I'll make sure I don't use 'View' as a name for an ActionResult